# Remove 'required' attribute from all fields for testing

Tags: html, browser-extension

I am using html5 required attribute for client side validation on my php project. I have also implemented server side validation. Now I want to test my server side validations, so is there any way by which I can remove 'required' attribute from all the fields in a page.

Right now I am replacing 'required' with single space in code temporarily.

expected solution should not require changing code from code editor, browser extensions are also fine. TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a seprate script file and write logic there

```
$("input").removeAttr("data-val-required");
```

Or

```
$("input").removeAttr("required");
```

Do same for all other form elements and include that on common or individual page.

Comment: @MdFaisal: If you are on the desktop, then you can write this directly in your browser Console. Or if you want to do it for multiple pages then write this code in a new .js file and include that file in the pages (just like you include jquery.js) where you want to test this.